# Mongo: How to return a cursor with partial value match?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection `Posts` and each post has a title and an author.

```
Posts : {
    id     : 7867887687,
    title  : unnamed-1,
    author : joe 
},{
    id     : 2867887687,
    title  : unnamed-2,
    author : joe 
},{
    id     : 1867337687,
    title  : happyhour,
    author : joe 
},{
    id     : 2367337687,
    title  : crappyhour,
    author : deb 
}
```

I want to return a cursor with only the posts by joe that have a title unnamed*. The next step is to sort the unnamed posts and add a new unnamed post with the next available -x number. (if one had been previously deleted the next available -x might be in the middle of others ... (sort of like creaiting new folders in windows))

How would I do that in Mongo?

Or should I return all posts by joe and then do a forEach to find the unnamed ones somehow?

Or some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression:

```
db.Posts.find({author:'joe', title:/^unnamed/i})
```

Here is more to read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/#op._S_regex

Comment: i am happy to double your reputation

Comment: while that matches the posts you want, how are you going to atomically get the next available number?  You need to make it thread-safe if your app is not single threaded - otherwise two threads could both try to use the same "available" number.